# mount / and / or apache - php permissions : where should I look?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mount, permissions

Here's the configuration :

The directory :

`/var/www/mount_ImpExp/ImpExp/`

is a shared directory (Linux) from a PC with an IP adress 192.168.1.12

My PC IP adress is `192.168.1.11`

I mounted that shared dir with the command :
`mount -t cifs -o auto,username=myusername,password=mypass //192.168.0.12/LINUX_U /var/www/mount_ImpExp`

If I try to manually launch a rsync with :

`rsync -t /var/www/mount_ImpExp/ImpExp/compteur_assur /usr/bin/`

This works :

```
ls -al /usr/bin/compteur_assur
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zobz zobz 2501 2009-06-09 15:44 /usr/bin/compteur_assur
```

Now I create a `exec.php` file in my website : the path is :
`/var/www/html/Internet/mywebsite`

the source is :

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
echo "<br />";
var_dump(
  system("rsync -t /var/www/mount_ImpExp/ImpExp/compteur_assur /usr/bin/"));
```

it doesn't work.

In the php.ini the "safemode" is "off". So I may be able to execute any shell command.
If I try to modify the `exec.php` file and do a simple :

```
var_dump( system("ls -al ."));
```

file

It works. So the "system" call works.

Thus I tried to modify the options in the `httpd.conf` file :

```
    # Ajout Olivier Pons / 11 juin 2009
    <Directory "/var/www/mount_ImpExp/ImpExp">
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I then restarted the server and nothing works.
What shall I do where should I look next ? I'm stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the problem : it a "permission problem" (or "rights problem" I don't know how to say it in English, sorry)

```
[Batman]:/var/www/html/Internet/mywebsite# chown apache:apache /var/www/mount_ImpExp/
chown: changing ownership of `/var/www/mount_ImpExp/': Permission denied
[Batman]:/var/www/html/Internet/mywebsite# chmod o+r /var/www/mount_ImpExp/
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/www/mount_ImpExp/': Permission denied
[Batman]:/var/www/html/Internet/mywebsite#
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to change the permissions of files you don't own. You need to set yourself as the owner then chmod 750.